# $T\subset X \times Y$ is the graph of the function if and only if for each $a\in X$ ,$T\cap (\lbrace a \rbrace \times Y )$ is a singleton

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification

> Let $f:X \longrightarrow Y$ and considere their graphic $G_{f}=\lbrace (x,f(x)) \mid x\in X\rbrace$.Prove that a subset $T\subset X \times Y$  is the graph of the function if and only if for each $a\in X$ ,$T\cap (\lbrace a \rbrace \times Y )$ is a singleton

**My attempmt**

First assume that  $T\subset X \times Y$  is the graph of the function, if $|T\cap (\lbrace a \rbrace \times Y )|=\lbrace \emptyset \rbrace $ then it is a singleton. Now suppose that $|T\cap (\lbrace a \rbrace \times Y )|>1$ then $|T\cap (\lbrace a \rbrace \times Y )|=2$ and let $l_1,l_2\in T\cap (\lbrace a \rbrace \times Y )$with $l_1 \neq l_2$,then  by hypotesis $l_1=(x_1,f(x_1))$ for $x_1\in X$ and $l_2=(x_2,f(x_2))$ for $x_2\in X$.Since $l_1,l_2\in \lbrace a \rbrace \times Y$  then $x_1=x_2=a$ then $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.And $l_1=l_2$ Which is a contradiction with our suppose.And therefore $|T\cap (\lbrace a \rbrace \times Y )|=1$ this is a singleton.

For the converse supposethat for each $a\in X$ ,$T\cap (\lbrace a \rbrace \times Y )$ is a singleton, we should prove that $T\subset X \times Y$ is a graphic.
Suppose that $T\subset X \times Y$ is not  a graphic.Then for some $l_1\in T$ we had
$l_1=(x_1,y_1)$ such that $y_1 \neq (x_1)$ and therefore
for $a=x_1$ $T\cap(\lbrace a \rbrace \times Y)=\lbrace (x_1,y_1),(x_1,f(x_1))\rbrace$ which is not a singleton.
Therefore $T$ is a graphic.
Is my proof right or i do a mistake, any feedback was very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Suppose that $T$ is the graph of a function, that is, suppose that there exists $g : X \to Y$ such that $T = \{(x,y) \in X \times Y : y = g(x)\}$. Now, take $a \in X$ and observe that $T \cap (\{a\} \times Y)$ is non-empty since $(a,g(a)) \in T \cap (\{a\} \times Y)$. We claim that $T \cap (\{a\} \times Y) = \{(a,g(a))\}$. Indeed, if $(x,y) \in T \cap (\{a\} \times Y)$ then $(x,y) \in T$ implies that $y = g(x)$, but since $(x,y) \in \{a\} \times Y$, we have $(x,y) = (a,g(a))$.
- Now suppose that $T \cap (\{a\} \times Y)$ is a singleton for each $a \in X$. Thus, if for each $a \in X$ we let $g(a)$ be the unique element in $Y$ such that $T \cap (\{a\} \times Y) = \{(a,g(a)\}$, it follows that $g : X \to Y$ and that $T$ is the graph of $g$.

Comment: Then my proof are wrong?

Comment: No, just there are some issues and I presented a more direct proof. For example, when you say "$|T \cap (\{a\} \times Y)|= \{\varnothing\}$" this is non-sense. Also, when you say that $>1$ implies that $=2$, this is also wrong.